# Difference between SharedActivityContext() and MainActivity.this

Tags: android, delphi, c++builder

Is `SharedActivityContext()` the equivalent of `MainActivity.this` in Java ?

EDIT : Please look at the C++Builder TAG, this question is about `SharedActivityContext()` used in Delphi and C++Builder !

Answer (score 0):

Application context concerned with the whole app and remain alive until app is not closed

whereas

Activity context concerned with the Activity only

Comment: So does `SharedActivityContext()` refer to the Context of the `MainActivity` ? Why changing the name from `MainActivity` to `SharedActivity` ?
I know the difference between Application Context and Activity Context.

Comment: `SharedActivity()` (and `TAndroidHelper.Activity` in XE7+) is *supposed* to return the `Activity` that is running the app (the `NativeActivity` that Embarcadero implements the app as). `SharedActivityContext()` (and `TAndroidHelper.Context`) is *supposed* to return the `Context` of that `Activity`. I say *supposed to* because it doesn't always work correctly, especially in a service.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, other than in a service, do you know of any other circumstances where it doesn't work correctly.Your use of "especially" suggests there may well be other cases, but I'm not wholly sure if that's what you meant...